# Can't change primary language in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have submitted my first App to the AppStore. Unfortunately I've notice that the primary language is set to German instead of English. I've try to change the primary language but the error occurred:

In order to change this app’s primary language to Englisch (USA), each version must already have the required Englisch (USA) screenshots.

But I've already uploaded screenshots for German and English (USA). Have anyone encountered the same issue?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? I'm talking to Apple support and they can't figure it out either.

Comment: @MK_Dev No sorry :/ Still waiting for an answer. If I figure it out I will tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Apple support's help, I was able to resolve this issue. Hopefully, this will work for you. Here's what they had to say:

> ...this is [may be] caused by the Apple Watch section in Media Manager. Please
>   uncheck the “Use XX_LANGUAGE_XX Apple Watch” in the app’s English
>   localization.

I had to uncheck that for everything - Watch, tvOS and anything else I could find. I was able to change the language after that. I hope this helps.

Comment: Now it worked for me. I've created a new version and did not check “Use XX_LANGUAGE_XX Apple Watch” (like @MK_Dev said). Then I was able to change the primary language.

Comment: I've encountered the very  same problem. But "Use XX_LANGUAGE_XX Apple Watch” doesn't appear to be checkable/ selectable (anymore?) in the context of the Media Manager. Has this option been removed from "App Store Connect"?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, since I've added a build to it. I removed the build and changed the language. Beware to select the language according the the app store list.