# Error message on App Store Connect: Primary Locale couldn’t be saved - you must provide the required screenshots for each version in this language

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, apple-watch, imessage

**Steps:**

1. Added “German” localization as a secondary language.
2. Added all the localized text under "Prepare for submission".
3. Added all the localized screenshots for

   iphone 6,5"

   iPhone 5,5"

   ipad 12,9" 3rd Gen

   ipad 12,9" 2nd Gen
4. Selected "App Information" (under "General").
5. Chose "German" in the dropdown-list "Primary Language" and saved.

**What happened:**

An error-message was displayed:

You have one or more errors on this page.

- Primary Locale couldn’t be saved because you must first provide all the required screenshots for each version in this language.

**Possible problem:**

Under the "Media Manager" in the context of my app, in the section "iMessage App" as well as "Apple Watch", it claims that it uses references of "English (U.S.)" screenshots.

[image: Under German localization - iMessage App references English screenshots - my App doesn't use iMessage App]
[image: Apple Watch references "English U.S." Screenshots in the context of the German localization - my App doesn't use Apple Watch]

However, the app supports neither "iMesage App" nor "Apple Watch", and when I switch to "English (U.S.)"-localization, there are neither screenshots nor references under "iMessage App" and "Apple Watch".

[image: iMessage App doesn't reference anything in the context of English localization]
[image: Apple Watch doesn't reference anything in the context of the English localization]

My App neither supports "iMessage App" nor "Apple Watch", and the English localization doesn't appear to require dedicated screenshots (or references to screenshots) for these options.

This problem seems to have been already answered here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39884724/6607940

However the solution doesn’t work since "Use XX_LANGUAGE_XX Apple Watch” doesn't appear to be checkable/ selectable (anymore?) in the context of the Media Manager.

Comment: I've filed a bug report at Apple's "Feedback Assistant" and will post the solution here if one should eventually materialize.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The apple support has posted an answer I want to share with anyone who struggles with this problem like I did:

Turns out that **in order to change the primary language to German** (or any other alternative language, for that matter) **you need to submit the app with German as an alternative language**, adding all the texts and the required localized screenshots.

Once the update is approved you should be able to change the default language from English to German **in the context a subsequent app-submission**.

For details please see the [reply](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/9083100)